# Basic c++ function using vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm doing some exercises with vectors. I created a function that fill a vector with defined size but when I tried to make it `n` size, the vector apparently is filled with trash memory, it shows: `0x23fe20`, and my code crash when I try to use the vector.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


int cargavn(int vec[])    // fill vector
{
    int i, t;       
    cout << "vector size: ";
    cin >> t;
    for(i = 0 ; i <= t-1; i++)
    {
        cout << "v["<< i <<"]=";
        cin >> vec[i];
    }
return (1);
}


int main()
{
    int vec[10];  // the vector, size here wont matter
    cargavn(vec); // call fill vector n positions
    cout << vec;    // to test if the vector is well filled
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: The size you specify in `main()` most definitely matters. You are not printing garbage, `cout<<vec;` will print the address of `v[0]`. You are allocating a certain amount of memory and then printing based on an arbitrary integer dependent on user input. You are most likely going out of bounds and accessing memory that you shouldn't.

Comment: This is not a vector, it is an array. Vector is usually used to refer to the STL object in C++

Comment: You tagged this as `c++` but you're using C style arrays and talking about vectors. Either update the tag to C or you're really confused and should be using `std::vector`...

Answer (score 4):

you are exprecting cout << vec to somehow pretty print the vector. It wont, it just prints its address

You need to loop over the contents and print each element

```
for(int i =0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
   cout << vec[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now the problem is when I use the vector or array in another function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it would look using modern C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void cargavn(vector<int> &vec)
{
    int t;       
    cout << "vector size: ";
    cin >> t;
    for(int i = 0; t > 0; ++i, --t)
    {
        cout << "v["<< i <<"]=";
        int v;
        cin >> v;
        vec.push_back(v);
    }
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, vector<int> const &vec)
{
    s << '{';
    bool first = true;
    for (int v : vec)
    {
        if (!first)
        {
            s << ", ";
        }
        s << v;
        first = false;
    }
    return s << '}';
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    cargavn(vec);
    cout << vec;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Things to understand about this version compared to yours:

- Unnecessary includes are ommitted.
- Prefer C++ containers like `vector` over C style arrays.
- Use dynamically sized containers when they need to hold an arbitrary number of values provided by the user instead of fixed-size containers that break when the user enters too much data.  See the [rule of 0, 1, infinity](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ZeroOneInfinityRule).
- When all control paths of a function return the same value, then the returned value is pointless and can be omitted.  Particularly if none of the callers even bothers to check the return value.  I suspect you had the intention of using the return value to indicate some kind of unexpected error.  This is a C-style approach to error handling.  C++ uses exceptions to deal with unexpected errors.
- Overload `operator<<` to extend the stream insertion operator to decide how containers and your own custom types should be formatted.  The standard library doesn't provide any such insertion operator for `vector` because there isn't any universally agreed upon way to decide how a vector of values should be formatted.  So you decide this for yourself.
- It is good form for `main` to return a value, even though this is not technically required.